# How to get data from two related tables in laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have 3 tables with foreign keys installed.

```
customers {customer_id, customer_name}

products {product_id, product_name}

customer_products {id, customer_id (foreignkey), product_id (foreignkey)}
```

My **Controller** code:

```
$CustomerProducts = ModelName::where('customer_id', 'somevalue')
->Join('customer_products', 'product_id', '=', 'customer_id')       
->get();
```

My **Model** code:

```
class ModelName extends Model { 
protected $table = 'hd_products';
public $primaryKey = 'id'; }
```

What is wrong in my code, since I'm getting wrong results. I want to show customer information and its related products.

Comment: As correctly pointed by @Watercayman this is a `Many to Many` relationship in laravel, you can read more here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show customer information and its related products, you gotta select the data from the tables.

In your code, in the controller, to get all data from all tables
you add:

```
->select(['customers.*' ,'products.*' ,'customer_products.*'])->get();
```

and edit the join statement so the controller will be like:

```
$CustomerProducts= DB::table('customer_products')
      ->join('customers','customers.customer_id','customer_products.customer_id')
      ->join('products','products.product_id','customer_products.product_id')
      ->select(['customers.*' ,'products.*' ,'customer_products.*'])
      ->get();
```

do not forget to add (if not added)

```
use DB;
```

At the beginning of your file (in the namespace area or the imports area), so it is like:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use DB;
use App\ //"your_file";
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

Hope this is helpful :)

Comment: May I ask, if a user chooses one product from the list to buy. what parameters to send and capture and how? my link is <a href="{{ secure_url('/purchase/'.$occasion->id.'/'.$OccasionProduct->id) }}". 

How can the controller know which product to add to cart and for which customer_id ?

Comment: Sorry, I just saw ur comment 
Anyway, you will send the product_id, the controller will select the data depending on the product id, so, it is going to be like :
<a href="{{URL::route('yourRouteName',$OccasionProduct->id)}}" .

in the view of list of the product purchased, you will call the product_name 

so you will change the select statement in the controller rather than * to select certain attributes that you want  
->select(['customers.*' ,'products.name as product_name' ,'customer_products.*'])->get();

Hope you understand, Hard to explain with limited characters.

Answer (score 3):

This is where Laravel makes life easy.  By adding the relationships on the model, you can then simply call the relationship via an eager load.  You don't need the `join`, you can just pull the relationship.  So

On your **Customer model**, set up the product relationship (you look like you have the right database structure for a many-to-many):

```
 public function products(){
    return $this->belongsToMany("\App\Product");
 }
```

And then in your **Controller**, when you go to load your customers, you can grab the products at the same time:

```
$customer = Customer::with("products")->first();
```

I'm just taking the first customer as an example - you could get all of them and loop on customer as well as products if you wish.

And finally when you want to call the data like in a **blade view**, you can access it by chaining on the `$customer` model.  :

```
{{ $customer->products->first()->name }}
```

If you want to loop through the products on the customer in a **blade view**:

```
@foreach($customer->products as $product){}
```

And, you still have the primary data for the $customer:

```
$customer->name // Etc.
```

HTH